# Change UIImageView size and move it with touch gesture

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, resize

In my app I have an UIImageView that user can touch and move around.
I need that when the touch begins to change the size of the image.
For this i've implemented this method

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

and changed inside it the size and then the image moves with **UIPanGestureRecognizer**.

The only problem is that when the touch begins the size is getting changed, but when the image is moving it's resizing to it original size.
Thank you for the help!

Comment: what you need exactly? when touch it's size is changed and it's movable?

Comment: UIPanGestureRecognizer will swallow the touchesBegan/Ended events unless cancelsTouchesInView is set to NO, it sounds like your code expects otherwise.

Comment: I need to change it's size when touch and move it, but at the beginning of the movement the size changes back to the original before the movment

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the workflow should be:

1. In touchesBegan, record the current image size and the touch position
2. In touchesEnded, compare the value of ending touch position and the recorded touch position of touchesBegan, refresh the image size with the ratio of two position.

Comment: furthermore, you may implement touchesMoved if you want to visualize the "growing" of the image.

Comment: Thanks, but i want to use PanGesture, because i have more touch operations

Answer (score 0):

Just use touchesMoved to move the image.

```
@interface TTImageView : UIImageView
{
     CGPoint startLocation;
}
@end

@implementation TTImageView

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        [self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [self setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    }
    return self;
}
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    startLocation = pt;
    [[self superview] bringSubviewToFront:self];

    //change the size of the image
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y, 150, 150);
    [self setFrame:frame];
}

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event

{
    CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    CGRect frame = [self frame];
    frame.origin.x += pt.x - startLocation.x;
    frame.origin.y += pt.y - startLocation.y;
    [self setFrame:frame];

}
@end
```

Comment: [self setFrame:frame];
I didn't use that line, that was my mistake, now it's perfect, thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't subclass `UIImageView` just to get this behaviour a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` is probably more appropriate